# Typescript: Different Types in different classes with same variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript 3.7.2: I have three components:
"Menu Component", "Login User" and "Logged in".

In the "Menu Component" I have a "user" property, this property can be defined or null:

```
interface Props {
    user: UserIF | null;
}
```

The "Menu Component" checks if the "user" property is defined. If it is not defined (null) then menu redirects to the component "Login User" otherwise it redirects to the "Logged in" component.

Now I would like to define the typescript definition in the components as follows:

"Login user":

```
interface Props {
    user: UserIF | null;
}
```

"Logged in"

```
interface Props {
    user: UserIF;
}
```

Typescript is now complaining that user can also be Null in the "Logged in" component. But Typescript doesn't know that the variable user can't be null in the "Logged in" component.

How can I tell typescript that I have only a defined user varaible in the "Logged in" component?

Comment: What is `UserIF`? Is it an object?

Comment: This is the definition of user variable.
export interface UserIF {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

Comment: If you have declared a default value (an empty object) for `user` (in a reducer or so), you can just use partial `user: Partial<UserIf>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two separated interfaces:

```
interface NotLoggedProps {
    user: null;
}

interface LoggedProps {
    user: UserIF;
}

type MenuProps = NotLoggedProps | LoggedProps; // at Menu level user can be logged or not
```

And use them accordingly in different components.

Comment: What if the user content is dynamic and comes from async http request? You can't dynamically change two interfaces...

Comment: You cannot never change interface in dynamic way. Every generic type is transformed into final type. Generic types are only for code reuse. Also async call is runtime, types not exists at this point.